# Betrayal at House on the Hill, Haunt 52 question

Tags: betrayal-at-house-on-the-hill, betrayal-widows-walk

This question is about Haunt 52, and you really can't ask it without spoiling the haunt.

> The players have to walk through the house figuring out that the rooms without traps follow a number pattern. However, even if you find the room that is supposed to be the exit, the instructions say nothing to the betrayer that he/she must inform the other players. As the number in the sequence was chosen randomly by the betrayer, it is pure luck if you just happen to be in the correct room at the end, even if you figure out the sequence. Does the betrayer have to tell the players when they find the exit room? Even if everyone is standing in a safe room when the game ends, the exit room was random. There seems to be no way to figure out which room it is... or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

The haunt you're inquiring about seems to be particularily bad in design, and having certain problems that, while not necessarily making it unplayable, seem to make it unenjoyable.

> You're correct in that the rules don't state that the traitor has to tell the heroes that they've found the exit room, so you really don't have to. Instead, it appears that the haunt intends the heroes to realize that only one room is not shifted around, which is the exit room. The sequence, while largely irrelevant, at least makes the heroes traverse through those rooms though, possibly coming to that conclusion in the end. However, with the traitor in the driver's seat, it's both easy (depending on the house's layout) to obscure this fact by cleverly choosing rooms to move, or block the heroes from reaching that room altogether.

This seems to be an issue unlikely to be resolved other than house-ruling on the spot, and has been brought up [in other places](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1655195/spoilers-haunt-52-issues-spoilers) as well, largely supporting the impression I've had of this.